# Why has arXiv been posting articles later?

Tags: arxiv

Typically arXiv updates around 9 PM EST. Recently I have noticed that it hasn't been updating until 11 or 11:30 PM EST. Does anyone know why the delay?

Comment: Is the 2-hour later posting of any significance to anything, or are you simply curious about the internal workings of the site.

Comment: @CrimsonDark Purely curious. Maybe slightly impatient, new arXiv posts is always a highlight to my day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The releases have been often slow in the past few months, especially on Monday evenings, due to many submissions. This is confirmed by the occasional updates on the Twitter account of arXiv's scientific director ([[1]](https://twitter.com/steinly0/status/1747441983595921695),[[2]](https://twitter.com/steinly0/status/1736955365592326216)) which are often reposted on the [official arXiv account](https://twitter.com/arxiv).

Comment: On a more bitter note, I am disappointed that the arXiv seems to have spent the millions they receive in donations on developing HTML5 converters and hiring people to post memes on Twitter rather than upgrading their servers and getting a handle on their exceedingly long moderation times.